# JavaScript to place add buttons in nested prototype forms

Tags: javascript, symfony, prototype

I have built a form with nested form.

My key problem is to fix the javascript, that i get also the add button under the "new created category" to create there subcategories.

Also im not happy with the structure. Normaly i need the category at first an inside the subcategories. But if i render the sub at first, the field from the sub is not there.

My twig:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'ui form'}}) }}

    <div class="ui segment">

        <div class="field">{{ form_row(form.maindescription) }}</div>

        {{ form_row(form.np_id, { 'attr': {'value': app.request.get('id')} }) }}


        <ul class="subcategories" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.categories.vars.prototype.children['subcategories'].vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">

            <ul class="categories" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.categories.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">



            </ul>


        </ul>


    </div>


    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Help with the script will be warmly welcome.

I created a snipped:

```js
  var $collectionHolder;
        var $collectionHolder2;

        // setup an "add a tag" link
        var $addTagLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_tag_link">Add a Category</a>');

        // setup an "add a tag" link
        var $addTagLink2 = $('<a href="#" class="add_tag_link2">Add a subcategory</a>');


        var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addTagLink);
        var $newLinkLi2 = $('<li></li>').append($addTagLink2);

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            // Get the ul that holds the collection of tags
            $collectionHolder = $('ul.categories');
            $collectionHolder2 = $('ul.subcategories');

            // add a delete link to all of the existing tag form li elements
            $collectionHolder.find('li').each(function() {
                addTagFormDeleteLink($(this));
            });
            $collectionHolder2.find('li').each(function() {
                addTagFormDeleteLink2($(this));
            });

            // add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the tags ul
            $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);
            $collectionHolder2.append($newLinkLi2);

            // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
            // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
            $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);
            $collectionHolder2.data('index', $collectionHolder2.find(':input').length);

            $addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
                // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
                e.preventDefault();

                // add a new tag form (see next code block)
                addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
            });
            $addTagLink2.on('click', function(e) {
                // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
                e.preventDefault();

                // add a new tag form (see next code block)
                addTagForm2($collectionHolder2, $newLinkLi2);
            });
        });


        function addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
            // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
            var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');

            // get the new index
            var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

            var newForm = prototype;
            // You need this only if you didn't set 'label' => false in your tags field in TaskType
            // Replace '__name__label__' in the prototype's HTML to
            // instead be a number based on how many items we have
            // newForm = newForm.replace(/__name__label__/g, index);

            // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
            // instead be a number based on how many items we have
            newForm = newForm.replace(/__cat__/g, index);

            // increase the index with one for the next item
            $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

            // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
            var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
            $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);

            // add a delete link to the new form
            addTagFormDeleteLink($newFormLi);
        }
        function addTagForm2($collectionHolder2, $newLinkLi2) {
            // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
            var prototype2 = $collectionHolder2.data('prototype');

            // get the new index
            var index2 = $collectionHolder2.data('index');

            var newForm2 = prototype2;
            // You need this only if you didn't set 'label' => false in your tags field in TaskType
            // Replace '__name__label__' in the prototype's HTML to
            // instead be a number based on how many items we have
            // newForm = newForm.replace(/__name__label__/g, index);

            // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
            // instead be a number based on how many items we have
            newForm2 = newForm2.replace(/__sub__/g, index2);

            // increase the index with one for the next item
            $collectionHolder2.data('index', index2 + 1);

            // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
            var $newFormLi2 = $('<li></li>').append(newForm2);
            $newLinkLi2.before($newFormLi2);

            // add a delete link to the new form
            addTagFormDeleteLink2($newFormLi2);
        }

        function addTagFormDeleteLink($tagFormLi) {
            var $removeFormA = $('<a href="#">delete</a>');
            $tagFormLi.append($removeFormA);

            $removeFormA.on('click', function(e) {
                // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
                e.preventDefault();

                // remove the li for the tag form
                $tagFormLi.remove();
            });
        }
        function addTagFormDeleteLink2($tagFormLi2) {
            var $removeFormA2 = $('<a href="#">delete</a>');
            $tagFormLi2.append($removeFormA2);

            $removeFormA2.on('click', function(e) {
                // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
                e.preventDefault();

                // remove the li for the tag form
                $tagFormLi2.remove();
            });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="appbundle_newspaper_maincategories" method="post" class="ui form form-horizontal">

        <div class="ui segment">

            <div class="field"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label required" for="appbundle_newspaper_maincategories_maindescription">Maincategory Dummy</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" id="appbundle_newspaper_maincategories_maindescription" name="appbundle_newspaper_maincategories[maindescription]" required="required" class="form-control"></div>
</div></div>

            <input type="hidden" id="appbundle_newspaper_maincategories_np_id" name="appbundle_newspaper_maincategories[np_id]" value="12">


            <ul class="subcategories" data-prototype="<div id=&quot;appbundle_newspaper_maincategories_categories___main___subcategories___sub__&quot;><div class=&quot;form-group&quot;><label class=&quot;col-sm-2 control-label required&quot; for=&quot;appbundle_newspaper_maincategories_categories___main___subcategories___sub___subdescription&quot;>Unterkategorie Name</label><div class=&quot;col-sm-10&quot;><input type=&quot;text&quot; id=&quot;appbundle_newspaper_maincategories_categories___main___subcategories___sub___subdescription&quot; name=&quot;appbundle_newspaper_maincategories[categories][__main__][subcategories][__sub__][subdescription]&quot; required=&quot;required&quot; class=&quot;form-control&quot; /></div>
</div></div>">

                <ul class="categories" data-prototype="<div id=&quot;appbundle_newspaper_maincategories_categories___main__&quot;><div class=&quot;form-group&quot;><label class=&quot;col-sm-2 control-label required&quot; for=&quot;appbundle_newspaper_maincategories_categories___main___description&quot;>Kategorie Name</label><div class=&quot;col-sm-10&quot;><input type=&quot;text&quot; id=&quot;appbundle_newspaper_maincategories_categories___main___description&quot; name=&quot;appbundle_newspaper_maincategories[categories][__main__][description]&quot; required=&quot;required&quot; class=&quot;form-control&quot; /></div>
</div><div class=&quot;form-group&quot;><label class=&quot;col-sm-2 control-label required&quot;>Subcategories</label><div class=&quot;col-sm-10&quot;><div id=&quot;appbundle_newspaper_maincategories_categories___main___subcategories&quot; data-prototype=&quot;&quot;></div></div>
</div></div>">



                <li><a href="#" class="add_tag_link">Add a Category</a></li></ul>


            <li><a href="#" class="add_tag_link">Add a subcategory</a></li></ul>


        </div>


        <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label required">Categories</label><div class="col-sm-10"><div id="appbundle_newspaper_maincategories_categories" data-prototype=""></div></div>
</div><input type="hidden" id="appbundle_newspaper_maincategories__token" name="appbundle_newspaper_maincategories[_token]" value="y_V-6SQB18RVoGp7MyB8nRa38V9dMDxOU22OgyI2QK8"></form>
```

THX
Mike

Comment: That is a lot of code. You will have better luck with getting someone to help if you create a code snippet with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I did - hope i get help.